# Convert Spring's Order to JPA Order from Pageable

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

Our frontend is designed to send Pageable object with Spring's Order which contains attribute name.

Sample Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Foo {

   private String userName;

   @Embedded
   private Bar bar;
}

@Embeddable
public class Bar {
   private String value;
}
```

We receive pageable with order in repository and parse JPA's Order from that pageable object like this:

```
pageable.getSort().get().forEach(springOrder -> 
        jpaOrders.add(getBuilder().asc(root.get(springOrder .getProperty())))
        );
```

We need do it this way because we are building queries via criteria api.

When we receive in repository attribute of Foo, everything is fine, e.g. "userName". But when we receive attribute of embeddable entity, e.g. "bar.value" we got exception

> Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [bar.value] on this ManagedType

Can you tell me how to create JPA's Order object from attribute which define attribute of embeddable entities? Thank you in advice

Comment: Why are you having to 'parse' the Pageable? You should be able to pass this straight to the repository. Have you implemented PagingAndSortingRepository https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html

Comment: @AlanHay I added reason also to question. We have advanced queries so we are using criteria api for them.

Comment: Consider specification pattern (using Criteria API or with QuerDsl as a (IMO, simpler) alternative). See JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> and QueryDslPredictaeExecutor<T> which have methods to take the specificatin/predicate and the Pageable. https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: @AlanHay we switch from querydsl because of some issues. But thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

For these property paths you will have to create joins and apply the `Order` using the proper join alias and the last part of the property path.

For more details, I'd recommend looking into the code of Spring Data JPA.
Find all references to the `Order` class and start reading some code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils#toOrders` ?